# dlm package not forecasting properly with dlmModTrig

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, dlm

I'm having trouble forecasting a time series with a trigonometric component using dlmModTrig.

So far I have:
buildFun<-function(x){

dlmInven<- dlmModTrig (s=12, dV=0, q=2, dW=exp (x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9LWs.png)))+dlmModPoly(order=2, dV=exp(x[2]), dW=c(exp(x[3]),exp(x[4])))
    return(dlmInven)
}

And the convergence is 0 after I check

(fit<-dlmMLE(lInven, parm=rep(0,4), build=buildFun))$conv.

However, the predicted graph is very far off. In fact, even the smoothed portion is far off:

[image]

If I do the dlmModTrig and the dlmModPoly individually. The fits are  better.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This is about problems w/ using R, not actually about statistics. It is off topic here. It may be on topic on [SO] w/ a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536), but it doesn't quite strike me as a programming question exactly. It may be better to send to the r-help listserv (be sure to include a reproducible example there as well).

Comment: There may be something I'm missing with the way I'm defining the dV and dW's that's causing this - and it is probably conceptual.